# how to use user number input in edit text and use it for math doing

Tags: android, android-edittext

Im setting a text filed in android studio that user should put a number in it and i want to use the number to be divided what would be the code

Comment: Share what you have done so far.

Comment: Hi, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: And share format of showing number.

Comment: want to know how to use the number that client puts in the field in java code

Comment: i saw in other comment that you asked about float, well this is the way to get te text from the textview and parse it to float but your question is lacking a lot of information so we cant really help you until you edit it. 
float number = Float.parseFloat(textView.getText()+"");

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
android:inputType="number"
```

at the xml attribute. Then retrieve the input and convert it to int or float.

---edit---
Code to retrieve the value from edit text and convert it to double.

```
Double x = Double.parseDouble(edtText.getText());
```

Comment: Double x = Double.parseDouble(edtText.getText());

Comment: ```Float.parseFloat(edtText.getText().toString);```